# Including a jar-file from command line results in java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running the program

Tags: java, command-line, jar, noclassdeffounderror, itext7

I'm trying to write a java-program that reads from pdf-files using iText7. 
IText7 is a collection of several jar-files. My program (create_PDF.java) uses 3 classes - PdfWriter.class and PdfDocument.class from the kernel.jar and Document.class from the layout.jar.
My OS is Mageia and I am not using a KDE and run the program from command line.

My folder structure is as follows:
some_folder/iText7/(all the jar-files)
some_folder/create_PDF.java
The program I'm using is this one: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/itext/itext_creating_pdf_document.htm
I compile the program from command line using:
javac -cp iText7/kernel-7.1.15.jar:iText7/layout-7.1.15.jar:iText7/io-7.1.15.jar:. create_PDF.java
(the io-jar is needed)
The program compiles without a problem. However, when I try to run the program with:
java -cp iText7/kernel-7.1.15.jar:iText7/layout-7.1.15.jar:iText7/io-7.1.15.jar:. create_PDF
I'm getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError caused by a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. That is in so far interesting as that the program **does** find the PdfWriter.class but not the PdfDocument.class, even though they are both in the kernel.jar (it creates the pdf-file but cannot add anything to it). I have also tried compiling and running the program including all the jar-files but that doesn't change anything.
My problem is that this is my first time trying to add jar-files and most tutorials focus on using KDEs. I would be very grateful if anyone has an answer or knows of a tutorial with might help me. Thank you
EDIT adding error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfCatalog.(PdfCatalog.java:73)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1963)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.(PdfDocument.java:285)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.(PdfDocument.java:266)
at Create_PDF.main(Create_PDF.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 5 more

Comment: you must use ; instead of : to separate your classpath items

Comment: Thank you, but from what I've read ; is only used for Windows. It certainly doesn't work for me.

Comment: @shikida No `;` is the separator on Windows only. Every other platform uses `:`. Exactly which class is not found?

Comment: I added the whole error message, but as far as I see PdfDocument.class isn't found (and possibly Document.class, though it never reaches that part of the code so I cannot check that). Both PdfDocument.class and PdfWriter.class (which is found and used) are part of the same jar-file.

Comment: The only class it can't find is `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` which is a logger library that you don't have on your classpath. [Here](http://www.slf4j.org/).

Comment: I'm sorry for being so late to answer! Thank you very much for pointing this out, I just assumed that that was part of IText7 and didn't realize that I needed to insert another jar.